# In the dynamic table, how do you dynamically set the value for each row's inputSelect?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

These problems have plagued me too much time. Maybe my implementation method is problematic. Is there a better way? Ask a friend to help me.

**Question 1:** When I get each row value in a dynamic table, if I define **[aura:id="ParentField"]**, this won't work because aura:id is limited to one row.

**Question 2:** If I use **labelClass="{!index}"** to get the current row,

```
var getLabel = event.getSource().get('v.labelClass');
```

I will assign a value to the **{!v.childList}**, but if the table has multiple rows, all rows will have values.
How to assign values only to rows of operations, not all rows?

**Question 3:** I have 2 ui:inputSelect needs to set the change method. When I add [labelClass="{!index}"] for the first [ui:inputSelect], the second one still needs to add [labelClass="{ !index}"], these 2 [labelClass="{!index}"] will affect each other and will not work.

**This is my CMP file**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" controller="AccountGroupController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:attribute name="PackTag" type="GroupLabel__c[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentList" type="list" default="[]" description=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="childList" type="list" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pickListMap" type="map"/>
    <aura:attribute name="disabledChildField" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objectName" type="string" default="GroupLabel__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentFieldAPI" type="string" default="ParentPicklist__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="childFieldAPI" type="string" default="ChildPicklist__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentFieldLabel" type="string" />
    <aura:attribute name="childFieldLabel" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentValue" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="childValue" type="string" default=""/>

    <div class="slds-box">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate">S.No</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Classify">Classify</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Field">Field</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Operator">Operator</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Value">Value</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.PackTag}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps" id="{!index}">
                    <td>
                        {!index}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputSelect value="{!item.ParentPicklist__c}" aura:id="ParentField" labelClass="{!index}" change="{!c.classifyChange}">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.parentList}" var="value">
                                <option value="{!value}">{!value}</option>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </ui:inputSelect>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputSelect value="{!item.ChildPicklist__c}" aura:id="childField" change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.childList}" var="value">
                                <option value="{!value}">{!value}</option>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </ui:inputSelect>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputSelect>
                            <option value="null">-None-</option>
                            <option value="equal">equal</option>
                            <option value="not equal to">not equal to</option>
                            <option value="Less than">Less than</option>
                            <option value="greater or equal to">greater or equal to</option>
                        </ui:inputSelect>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {!v.body}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- conditionally Display Add or Delete Icons if rowIndex is 0 then show Add New Row Icon else show delete Icon -->
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!index == 0}">
                            <a onclick="{!c.AddNewRow}">
                                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:add" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="add"/>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Add Icon</span>
                            </a>
                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <a onclick="{!c.removeRow}" id="{!index}">
                                    <lightning:icon variant="error" iconName="utility:delete" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="icon"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete Icon</span>
                                </a>
                            </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**This is my JS file**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var RowItemList = component.get("v.PackTag");
        RowItemList.push({
            'sobjectType': 'GroupLabel__c',
            'ParentPicklist__c':'',
            'FieldAPI__c': '',
            'Operator__c': '',
            'Input_Value__c': ''
        });

        component.set("v.PackTag", RowItemList);

        var action = component.get("c.getDependentPicklist");
        action.setParams({
            ObjectName : component.get("v.objectName"),
            parentField : component.get("v.parentFieldAPI"),
            childField : component.get("v.childFieldAPI")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var status = response.getState();
            if(status === "SUCCESS"){
                var pickListResponse = response.getReturnValue();

                //save response 
                component.set("v.pickListMap",pickListResponse.pickListMap);
                component.set("v.parentFieldLabel",pickListResponse.parentFieldLabel);
                component.set("v.childFieldLabel",pickListResponse.childFieldLabel);

                // create a empty array for store parent picklist values 
                var parentkeys = []; // for store all map keys 
                var parentField = []; // for store parent picklist value to set on lightning:select. 

                // Iterate over map and store the key
                for (var pickKey in pickListResponse.pickListMap) {
                    parentkeys.push(pickKey);
                }

                //set the parent field value for lightning:select
                if (parentkeys != undefined && parentkeys.length > 0) {
                    parentField.push('-None-');
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < parentkeys.length; i++) {
                    parentField.push(parentkeys[i]);
                }  
                // set the parent picklist
                component.set("v.parentList", parentField);

            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    AddNewRow : function(component, event, helper){
        var addRowInList = component.get("v.PackTag");
        var contactObj = new Object();
        addRowInList.push(contactObj);
        component.set("v.PackTag",addRowInList);
    },
    removeRow : function(component, event, helper){
        var whichOne = event.target.getAttribute("id")
        var AllRowsList = component.get("v.PackTag");
        AllRowsList.splice(whichOne, 1);
        component.set("v.PackTag", AllRowsList);
    },

    classifyChange : function(component, event, helper) {

        var controllerValue = component.find("parentField").get("v.value");
        var pickListMap = component.get("v.pickListMap");

        if (controllerValue != '-None-') {
             //get child picklist value
            var childValues = pickListMap[controllerValue];
            var childValueList = [];
            childValueList.push('-None-');
            for (var i = 0; i < childValues.length; i++) {
                childValueList.push(childValues[i]);
            }
            // set the child list
            component.set("v.childList", childValueList);

            if(childValues.length > 0){
                component.set("v.disabledChildField" , false);  
            }else{
                component.set("v.disabledChildField" , true); 
            }

        } else {
            component.set("v.childList", ['-None-']);
            component.set("v.disabledChildField" , true);
        }
    },

    onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selected = component.find("childField").get("v.value");
        console.log('get = ' + selected);

        if (selected === 'Child Option 1') {
            component.set("v.body",[]);
            $A.createComponent(
                "ui:inputText",
                {
                    "placeholder":"Enter Child Option 1",
                    "class": "slds-input"
                },
                function(newInp, status, errorMessage){
                    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newInp);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }
                }
            );
        }else{
            component.set("v.body",[]);
        }
    }
})
```

**This is the result I want to achieve:**
If [CLASSIFY] selects option 1, [FIELD] only [child option 1] can be selected. [VALUE] will also change, such as data input, select input, input box, etc.
[image]

[image]

**I have completed the single line feature, but if it is multiple lines, these features will not be available.**

Comment: For your question 1: you can use data attributes to store the parentfield information.  `data-parentfield="ParentField"` Then you can access it in your controller via `event.curentTarget.getAttribute('data-parentfield');`

Comment: You can also use the data attributes to set the row index as well.  `data-rowIndex="{!index}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to take current row Item and then Update it then rebind to `PackTag` list with same Place by index, i just use `Classify` and `field` columns in below code snippet. and in your `AddNewRow` function, you pushing normal JSobject it shouldn't , you need to push `'sobjectType': 'GroupLabel__c'` type let me know if you find any issue.

**cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="SeTesting" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
        access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="pickListMap" type="map" default="{'Option1':['Child Option1','Grand Child option1'],'Option2':['Child Option1','Grand Child option1','Grand Child option2']}"/>
<aura:attribute name="parentList" type="list" default="['Option1','Option2']" />
<aura:attribute name="childList" type="list" default=""/>
 <aura:attribute name="PackTag" type="List"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<div class="slds-box">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">S.No</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Classify">Classify</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Field">Field</div>
                </th>                    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>               
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.PackTag}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps" id="{!index}">
                        <td>
                            {!index}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:select aura:id="select"  name="{!index}" Class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" onchange="{! c.classifyChange }" value="{!item.ParentPicklist__c}">
                                <option value="-None-">-None-</option>
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.parentList}" var="value">
                                    <option value="{!value}">{!value}</option>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </lightning:select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <lightning:select aura:id="select"  name="{!index}" Class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" onchange="{! c.onSelectChange }" value="{!item.ChildPicklist__c}">
                                <option value="-None-">-None-</option>
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.childList}" var="value">
                                    <option value="{!value}">{!value}</option>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </lightning:select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!v.body}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- conditionally Display Add or Delete Icons if rowIndex is 0 then show Add New Row Icon else show delete Icon -->
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!index == 0}">
                                <a onclick="{!c.AddNewRow}">
                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:add" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="add"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Add Icon</span>
                                </a>
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    <a onclick="{!c.removeRow}" id="{!index}">
                                        <lightning:icon variant="error" iconName="utility:delete" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="icon"/>
                                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete Icon</span>
                                    </a>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.PackTag}" var="item" indexVar="index">
        {!item.ParentPicklist__c} --- {!item.ChildPicklist__c}
    </aura:iteration>
</div>
```

**cmpController**

```
({
doInit: function (component,event,helper) {       
  helper.AddgetnewObject(component);
},
AddNewRow : function(component, event, helper){
     helper.AddgetnewObject(component);
    //['Child Option1','Grand Child option1','Grand Child option2']
},
classifyChange : function(component, event, helper) {
     var pickListMap = component.get("v.pickListMap"),
         index = event.getSource().get("v.name"),
         RowItemList = component.get("v.PackTag"),
         currentrow = RowItemList[index],
         controllerValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    if (controllerValue != '-None-') {
         //get child picklist value
        var childValues = pickListMap[controllerValue];
        var childValueList = [];
        childValueList.push('-None-');
        for (var i = 0; i < childValues.length; i++) {
            childValueList.push(childValues[i]);
        }
        // set the child list
        currentrow.childList = childValueList;
        //component.set("v.childList", childValueList); 


    } else {
       currentrow.childList = ['-None-'];
        //component.set("v.childList", ['-None-']);

    }
    currentrow.ParentPicklist__c = controllerValue;
    RowItemList.splice(index, 1, currentrow);
    component.set("v.PackTag",RowItemList);
},
 onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
     var index = event.getSource().get("v.name"),
         RowItemList = component.get("v.PackTag"),
         currentrow = RowItemList[index],
         selected = event.getSource().get("v.value");
     if(selected !== '-None-'){
         currentrow.ChildPicklist__c = selected;
         RowItemList.splice(index, 1, currentrow);
         component.set("v.PackTag",RowItemList);
     }
}
```

})

**cmphelper**

```
({
AddgetnewObject : function(component){
     var RowItemList = component.get("v.PackTag");
    RowItemList.push({
        'sobjectType': 'GroupLabel__c',
        'ParentPicklist__c':'',
        'ChildPicklist__c': ''
    });
    component.set("v.PackTag", RowItemList);
}
})
```

Comment: Hi @sdandamud1 Thank you very much for the answer, which is very useful to me.But when I implemented it according to your ideas, I still encountered two problems. Question 1: When setting the [childList] value, if the table has multiple rows, [childList] will overwrite all rows, not the current row.

Comment: Question 2: When I dynamically create {!v.body}, the created component will also be displayed in all rows instead of the current row. There is also no way for the dynamically created component of {!v.body} to save the input value. I believe that I still need an index to solve my two problems, but I have no way, can you help me?

Comment: for Question 1: i just update the answer with add a `childList` Property for  current row Item for UI dynamic mechanism but you need to remove this `childList` property from each item  if you make any server calls because there is no `childList` field on `GroupLabel__c` object. For Question you instead of dynamic component i would suggest go with Boolean values to show/hide the `lighnting:input` component.

Comment: Hi @sdandamud1 After my efforts, I used { lightning:recordEditForm } to solve the first problem. But creating components dynamically for each row and getting input values is still unresolved. Do you have any good ideas? Heartfelt thanks

Comment: Fortunately, I found your conversation with Apple and used [Lex expressions] to complete the second question. Thank you very much and wish you a happy life!

Comment: So glad, your issue is resolved